# Debugging: finding the stemmed word in mongodb fulltext search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I see the stemmed word / search in mongodb? I looked into increasing loglevel and profiling, but have not seen the word stem that is actually searched for.

After setting the loglevel to 100 via

```
db.runCommand( { setParameter: 1, logLevel: 100 } );
```

I got the following log output:

```
command pwo81.$cmd command: count { count: "Pool0", query: { $text: { $search: "Basys" } }, fields: {} } planSummary: TEXT { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 } keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:354 reslen:48 0ms
```

Not using count() but find() solely does not alter the log output.

The search query used is:

```
db.Pool0.find({$text: {$search: "Basys"}})
```

Unfortunately it produces more results than expected, albeit searching for "\"Basys\"" is showing the correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use verbose [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/):

```
> db.text.insert({ "statement" : "I'm not a clown!" })
> db.text.ensureIndex({ "statement" : "text" })
> db.text.find({ "$text" : { "$search" : "clowning" } }).explain(true)
{
    "cursor" : "TextCursor",
    ...
        "parsedTextQuery" : {
            "terms" : [
                "clown"
            ],
            "negatedTerms" : [ ],
            "phrases" : [ ],
            "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
        },
    ...
}
```